# SqLite3 - INSERT or REPLACE INTO where id =...?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

Im trying to do an insert and replace where an id=1, the reason for this is that I only want one entry in the database. So when a user enters a value it will replace the original value, however at the moment its just adding it:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Animals(CAT) values ('Toby')"
```

Its working fine, but I only want one cat. I tried

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Animals(CAT) values ('Toby') WHERE ID='1'
```

However it doesnt work, also tried Where ID=1 and Where ID="1".

When I enter a second cat I want it to replace the cat already in there, ID is a primary key in my table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ANIMALS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, CAT VARCHAR)
```

Its not the cleanest way to do it so I'm open to suggestions

Comment: What datatype is your `ID` column? If it is a number then just do `WHERE ID=1`.

Comment: Its an integer, i think woz is right and WHERE is not supports,therefore it should automatically replace but it doesnt

Comment: Do you get an error? Or 0 rows are updated?

Comment: 0 rows are updating, the WHERE clause is not supported according to @woz however `code` INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Animals(CAT) values ('Toby') should replace but its inserting

Comment: Is `CAT` a primary key? I think `REPLACE` only knows to replace if the primary keys match.

Comment: apologies there might have been a typo above! When I enter a second cat I want it to replace the cat already in there, ID is a primary key in my table

Comment: If ID is an auto-incremented integer, `REPLACE` won't work. Try putting a unique index on `CAT`.

Comment: @woz id is indeed auto-incremented, how would you make a unique index? I cant find any working solutions.

Comment: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS CatIndex ON Animals (CAT)`

Comment: Thanks @woz however the Replace is not working

Comment: Are you getting a specific error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQLite3, there's no support for using `WHERE` after `INSERT OR REPLACE`.

[image]

I think you need an `UPDATE` statement to use `WHERE`.

If you only ever want to have one row in your database -- which is how I interpret your question -- it might be easier to use [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of SQLite.

Also, make sure that you set your primary keys and unique indices appropriately; otherwise, `REPLACE` won't know what to replace.

Comment: I want to insert if it doesnt exist

Comment: brilliant ill try NSUserDefaults if there is no other solution

Comment: do I need to set both primary keys and unique keys? I thought primary key would be enough, please see above how I create my table

Comment: Primary key is not enough in this case, since it's just an ID. I think you want a unique index on `CAT`.